# Pass user input with Ajax.ActionLink and setting url parameter

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Well, all I want is to pass user input  without using explicit jquery ajax methods. My idea is following: trying to use Ajax.ActionLink and set necessary parameters for ajax before ajax-itself:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Call date", "CallingHistory", "Member", new {sortOrder = ViewBag.DateSortParam, pageNumber = ViewBag.PageNumber}, new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId = "historytable", HttpMethod = "get", OnBegin = "SetUrlParameters"}, new {id = "calldatetimelink"})
```

and js-code for setting Url-parameters for Action:

```
<script>
function setUrlParameters() {
    var k = 0;
    this.href = this.href + "?includedialling=" + $("#chBox1").val();
    this.href = this.href + "?includeincomingmissedcalls=" + $("#chBox2").val();
    this.href = this.href + "?includeoutcomingmissedcalls=" + $("#chBox3").val();
}
</script>
```

Action method signature looks like this:

```
 public Task<ActionResult> CallingHistory(string sortOrder, int pageNumber, bool? includedialling,
        bool? includeincomingmissedcalls, bool? includeoutcomingmissedcalls){...}
```

Notice that js-method is executed before ajax-request. Is it possible to do that? I've been some confused cause of want to set breakpoint to js-method but can't see it in chrome web-tools. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
Yep, think this should work, but i changed script cause of parameters are added in infinite way:

```
function setUrlParameters(data) {
    var oldref = data.href;
    var par1 = '&includedialling=' + $("#chBox1").is(":checked");
    var par2 = '&includeincomingmissedcalls=' + $("#chBox2").is(":checked");
    var par3 = '&includeoutcomingmissedcalls=' + $("#chBox3").is(":checked");

    var arr = data.href.split('&');
    var resultUrl = arr[0] + arr[1] + par1 + par2 + par3;
    $("#calldatetimelink").href = resultUrl;
}
```

And got en error in chrome web-tools:

> GET localhost:50307/Views/Shared/Partial/Member/CallingHistory.cshtml?X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest&_=1409287722659 404 (Not Found)

Debugger in script shows such value of resultUrl variable:

> //localhost:50307/Member/CallingHistory?sortOrder=datepageNumber=1&includedialling=false&includeincomingmissedcalls=true&includeoutcomingmissedcalls=false. - All is good. But eventually i haven't got result yet. Where is this string 'X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest&_=1409287722659' appears from? Obviously, this is browser's behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes..In your question you are calling `setUrlParameters` in a right way but you are using `this` inside `setUrlParameters` function and you are not supplying it do this way instead :

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Call date", "CallingHistory", "Member", new {sortOrder = 
ViewBag.DateSortParam, pageNumber = ViewBag.PageNumber}, new AjaxOptions 
{UpdateTargetId = "historytable", HttpMethod = "get", OnBegin = 
"SetUrlParameters(this)"}, new {id = "calldatetimelink"})

<script>
function  setUrlParameters(data) {
  var link;
  link = data.href + "&includedialling=" + $("#chBox1").is(':checked') + "&includeincomingmissedcalls=" + $("#chBox2").is(':checked') + "&includeoutcomingmissedcalls=" + $("#chBox3").is(':checked');
  $("#calldatetimelink").attr('href',link)
}
</script>
```

and don't forget to include `'jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js'` file in your page or on layout page.

Comment: Thanks, Exception. I'm just a novice in jquery.

Comment: OnBegin js function is fired, i see that url parameters are set, but in server side method gets null-values.

Comment: Parameters are not passed - This way doesn't work. )

Comment: Well, more common question: i am doing table for sorting data and pagination, table headers are ajax.action links, server side method  (aforemetioned above) has 5 parameters and first 2 parameters are passed correctly always. But those, which are set in OnBegin are NULL. As i understand the only way to pass user input is to rewrite without Ajax.action link? Link to ajax.unobtrusive.js library is included.

Comment: @Rayan...I think above answer should work...just check carefully the spellings and instead of '?' it should be '&' shown above..just check and put a alert box after making complete url in javascript function..it should work...

Comment: @Rayan..this is not good..i have solved your question and now you extended the question..hahahaha....

Comment: Well, anyhow thanks a lot. There is insufficient reputation to vote up. ahah) as soon as possible

Comment: @Rayan..now at this point of time i m assuming that your controller action is hitting with required parameters and then there is problem in controller action then just check it..

Comment: fixed problem with correct url construction: while concatenating it is necessary to add "&" after arr[0]. Action method is called but all parameters which is supposed to be passed from checkboxes are null. Think everything should be rewrited via entirely jquery.

Comment: Haven't noticed that "&" is absent.See attentively error description in  my updated answer. "date&pageNumber" must was

Comment: @Rayan..yes '&' is neccesary as you can see in my answer i have concatenated url with proper '&'